# "You have already voted to delete this post" not shown in mobile view

Tags: bug, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

In the desktop view, whenever you try to vote to delete a post on which you've already cast a delete vote, you get an error message:

> You have already voted to delete this post

[image]

The mobile view however simply reloads the page and does not show an error message or something else to indicate that your vote failed:

[image]

Comment: More generally, no deletion errors are shown, such as "out of votes" and "the post is locked"