# No feedback for delete problems on mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

I’ve noticed a number of issues with casting delete votes from mobile. The common thread is a failure to notify the user of problems with the vote. I’ve seen it in the following situations:

- trying to cast a delete vote when you have none left for the day
- [trying to cast a delete vote on a post more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310033/you-have-already-voted-to-delete-this-post-not-shown-in-mobile-view)
- [trying to cast a delete vote on a question that another question is marked as a duplicate of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337440/vote-to-delete-via-mobile-web-doesnt-check-for-duplicates)

In all these cases the page simply reloads with no notice of a problem.

(Edited to add links to a couple of related questions asked over the past months/years.)

Comment: I've seen it trying to delete my own answered question. Nothing happened, didn't see the issue until I went to the desktop site.

Comment: Note this works as expected on the responsive site but there are bugs preventing me from using it on mobile. Most notably that the profile page is unusable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338437/un-responsive-profile-pages

Comment: With the mobile site being scheduled for deletion in 6-8 units of time your best option would be to use the responsive design.

Comment: @Luuklag they still have a long way to go toward making the responsive site usable.

Comment: For the most things I prefer it over the mobile site. Would be great if the profile page became responsive though.